# Promtail vs. Grafana Agent

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, grafana, logging

I'm running a couple of containers in a Docker Swarm and am setting up a logging system using Grafana Loki and Grafana (up to ~50GB/log per day max). For log shipping, I'm partly scraping container stdout/err logs directly and partly via mounted volumes and the log files therein, processing them in Promtail pipelines (partly JSON, partly regex) at the moment.

For the log shipper, it's not entirely clear [from the documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/) which one is recommended. It generally says Grafana Agent is the choice (except for K8s where it recommends Promtail), but then the documentation doesn't really mention Grafana Agent any more and the latest version is [only 0.39](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/)?

Then again, I understand the Grafana Agent [is essentially (among other) just a thin wrapper around Promtail](https://github.com/grafana/agent/issues/1543#issuecomment-1084713470) with support for metrics and tracing on top (which I would consider using mid-term).

I am new to the topic and a bit confused, also if I should be considering other log shippers as Fluentd/Bit in the first place, and which tools are supported by Grafana long-term.